# EF postgre check if database exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, postgresql-9.4

With the Entity Frameworks' **DbConetxt** I am trying to check if the database exists with the query below.

```
public async Task<bool> CheckIfExistsAsync(DbContext context)
{
    var result = await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("SELECT 1 from pg_database WHERE datname='CPNewDB'");
    return result == 1;
}
```

The problem is that the result is always **-1**. I am using postgresql and the query executes fine when I try it in the Pgadmin UI Query tool. I have tried googling but in vain. Any help will be appreciated.

Note: the context does not have database name, but has all the other database connection information required.

Comment: Did you already check whether `dbContext.Database.Exists()` is working in your case, before starting to execute some more or less complicated queries?

Comment: Hi @grek40 I am able to create the database with the **ExecuteSqlCommandAsync** command. but before creating the database I wanted to check if it exists. Also like i said, Database.Exists() might not work as the context does not have database name.

Comment: How about using `SqlQuery<int>` with `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ..."` instead of the `ExecuteSqlCommand`?

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this command. Since database names are case sensitive I put to be lower case. This should return you true/false

```
select exists(
 SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE lower(datname) = lower('dbname')
);
```

Comment: thanks for the idea, I tried but its the same result.